# How to combine lists together into one using slicing in python?

Tags: python, list, slice

I am trying to combine 3 different lists into 1 list.  I was able to do it with 2 lists, but when I added a third I started getting an error saying

```
ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 22 to extended slice of size 17.
```

Each of the different lists should alternate. If there are no more items in the list to include in 'result', it should just alternate to other 2 lists.  Any advice on how to enable this?

```
    print len(reddit_feed_dic)      #22
    print len(favorites_feed_dic)   #22
    print len(user_videos)          #6

    result = [None]*(len(favorites_feed_dic)+len(reddit_feed_dic)+len(user_videos))
    print len(result)
    result[::3] = reddit_feed_dic
    result[1::3] = favorites_feed_dic
    result[2::3] = user_videos
```

Here's an example with sample data:

```
reddit_feed_dic = [r1,r2,r3, ...r22]
favorite_feed_dic = [f1,f1,f3, ...f22]
user_videos = [u1, u2 u3, ...u6]
```

I would like result to be:

```
result = [r1,f1,u1, 
            r2, f2, u2,
            r3, f3, u3,
            r4, f4, u4,
            r5, f5, u5,
            r6, f6, u6,
            r7,f7,
            r8,f8,
            r9,f9,...

            r22,f22]
```

Comment: Please give an example with inputs and the outputs you expect.

Comment: @BrenBarn just added the result that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import *
```

If you want to fill the empty spaces with `None`:

```
>>> list(chain(*izip_longest('abcdef', '12345', '#!$')))
['a', '1', '#', 'b', '2', '!', 'c', '3', '$', 'd', '4', None, 'e', '5', None, 'f', None, None]
```

If you don't want the empty items there at all, and assuming the starting lists didn't have `None` in them already:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x is not None, chain(*izip_longest('abcdef', '12345', '#!$')))
['a', '1', '#', 'b', '2', '!', 'c', '3', '$', 'd', '4', 'e', '5', 'f']
```

If your lists *do* have `None` in them then it's a bit tricker. Same idea, but instead of filtering out `None` we'll filter out a "null" object that is guaranteed not to be present in the original lists (since we just created it!).

```
def interleave(*iterables):
    null = object()
    return ifilter(lambda x: x is not null, chain(*izip_longest(*iterables, fillvalue=null)))
```

Comment: The only thing I don't like about this is that it wouldn't work if he had `None` in his list to begin with.

Comment: @A.R.S. Agree. Came up with, I think, a solution to that.

Comment: Better not to reinvent the wheel, the most efficient solution has already been created by `itertools`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use the [`roundrobin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe provided by the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) documentation:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> def roundrobin(*iterables):
        "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
        # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
        pending = len(iterables)
        nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
        while pending:
            try:
                for next in nexts:
                   yield next()
            except StopIteration:
                pending -= 1
                nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))


>>> reddit_feed = ['r1','r2','r3']
>>> favorite_feed = ['f1','f2','f3']
>>> user_videos = ['u1','u2','u3']
>>> list(roundrobin(reddit_feed, favorite_feed, user_videos))
['r1', 'f1', 'u1', 'r2', 'f2', 'u2', 'r3', 'f3', 'u3']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2

    from itertools import zip_longest

    result = [j for i in zip_longest(list1,list2,list3) for j in i if j!=None]
```